# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'position' in undefined

Tags: jquery, draggable, sapui5, typeerror

I've got a problem with this code snippet:

```
<script>
                $.sap.require('sap.ui.thirdparty.jqueryui.jquery-ui-core');
                $.sap.require('sap.ui.thirdparty.jqueryui.jquery-ui-widget');
                $.sap.require('sap.ui.thirdparty.jqueryui.jquery-ui-mouse');
                $.sap.require('sap.ui.thirdparty.jqueryui.jquery-ui-draggable');
                $.sap.require('sap.ui.thirdparty.jqueryui.jquery-ui-sortable');
        </script>
        <script>
                jQuery.sap.includeStyleSheet("resources/css/dashboard.css");
                sap.ui.localResources("dashboard");
                var view = sap.ui.view({id:"idHome1", viewName:"dashboard.Home", type:sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.JS});
                view.placeAt("content");
        </script>
        <script>
            var oButton = sap.ui.getCore().byId("oChart_Button");
            console.log(oButton);
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $(oButton).draggable({
                    cancel: false
                })
            })
        </script>
```

I can't drag my button, because of the ErroMessage in the title. I've got this example from the internet, and for the people who comment this blog the code runs. The button exists, with `console.log(oButton)` I get a message with it's properties and so on. 
Any one a solution?

Comment: *"I've got this example from the internet, so the code must run."* ~ oh you sweet, innocent thing

Comment: yeah maybe I expressed myself wrong. There was an example with hundred comments and it seems that it works for the most people

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [getDomRef](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.Element.html#getDomRef) to get DOM element of your UI5 control. So, your code will be something like this.

```
var oButton = sap.ui.getCore().byId("oChart_Button");
var el = oButton.getDomRef();
$(el).draggable({
    cancel: false
});
```

jQuery selectors allow you to select and manipulate HTML element(s).
When you do `$(oButton)` you are passing SAPUI5 `Button` object to jQuery selector, which will not work. So, to get respective HTML DOM element of UI5 `Button` control, `getDomRef` is used.

So, why your button is not *draggable* even after passing DOM to jQuery selector?

This might be happening because first you are loading third party library for jQuery-Ui for draggable functionality.
Then, after that `SAPUI5` library is loaded, so functions only from `SAPUI5` library are available. 
So, to overcome this, we can load the third party library after UI5 library within body of your `HTML` file.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer, but the button is still not draggable :( The error doesn't occur anymore, but yeah it's still not working ... But I've got a little question anyway: Why does the .getDomRef helps in this moment,  that the error doesn't occur anymore?

Comment: Thank you so much :) It works fine I putted the Button into the view, and the jQuery code into the Controller and now it works. So I needn't to put the requires into the body ;) Thank you, also for the explanation :)