# SAPUI5 and JQuery draggable - refuse to mix

Tags: javascript, jquery, sapui5

I am trying to use SapUI5 and JQuery `$("#draggable").draggable();` function to drag some div around my html page.

problem is - they interfere with each other - SAPUI5 library also have a varibale named draggable (I want to use JQuery draggable() **function**).

as a result I get `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).draggable is not a function(…)`

how to solve it? my code is below.. It simulates the problem. notice that once I remove the script tag of SAPUI5 it is working fine and I can drag the div..

Thanks in advance!

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <title>jQuery UI Draggable - Default functionality</title>
    <style>
        #draggable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; border:1px; }
    </style>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>




    <script id='sap-ui-bootstrap'
            type='text/javascript'
            src='https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.38.10/resources/sap-ui-core.js'
            data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.commons,sap.ui.table,sap.m,sap.ui.ux3"
            data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
    >
    </script>

    <script>
        $(function() {
            $("#draggable").draggable();
        } );
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="draggable">
    <p>Drag me around</p>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check out my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37584845/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-use-in-operator-to-search-for-position-in-undefin/37585277#37585277)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should move the Jquery scripts at the bottom

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <title>jQuery UI Draggable - Default functionality</title>
    <style>
        #draggable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; border:1px; }
    </style>




    <script id='sap-ui-bootstrap'
            type='text/javascript'
            src='https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.38.10/resources/sap-ui-core.js'
            data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.commons,sap.ui.table,sap.m,sap.ui.ux3"
            data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
    >
    </script>

    <script>
        $(function() {
            $("#draggable").draggable();
        } );
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="draggable">
    <p>Drag me around</p>
</div>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Other option is to import the thirdparty libraries.

```
<script>
    $.sap.require('sap.ui.thirdparty.jqueryui.jquery-ui-core');
    $.sap.require('sap.ui.thirdparty.jqueryui.jquery-ui-widget');
    $.sap.require('sap.ui.thirdparty.jqueryui.jquery-ui-mouse');
    $.sap.require('sap.ui.thirdparty.jqueryui.jquery-ui-draggable');

      $(function() {
        $("#draggable").draggable();
    } );
</script>
```

You could wrap those calls in a function to make it less ugly =)